# Build a data.table of multiple data.frames using get() in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have many data.frames with the same number of rows

```
x1 <- data.frame(runif(20)); x2 <- data.frame(runif(20)); x3 <- data.frame(runif(20))
```

And so on.. I have many more data.frames

And I'm using data.table to put them together

I though I could do something like this

```
allx <- data.table(get(paste0('x',1:3)))
```

But doesn't seem to work, it only gets the first data.frame

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for `mget`?

Comment: `mget` works using `allx <- data.frame(get(paste0('x',1:3)))` which is fine. Thanks